# EXSLT - math:random don't work

Tags: xml, xslt, exslt

I want to use the function math:random() of EXSLT but I can't make it work. This is my test, the file xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="math">
<xsl:import href="math.xsl"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="(floor(math:random()*10) mod 10) + 1"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is the simple file xml:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stile.xslt"?>
<radice>
   ciao!
</radice>
```

This example should not print me "ciao!" and a random number from 1 to 10?
Thanks at all for the help.

Comment: So what _does_ it generate as output?

Comment: then there is something else wrong. Since you are matching the root of yuor document and not generatign _any_ output except for your math function, if "ciao!" appears, it seems no transform is done at all.

Comment: Maybe I have installed the library EXSLT in a way incorrect or maybe the library EXSLT isn't compatible with my database "ExistDB"?

Comment: I have find that if I remove the `<xsl:import href="math.xsl"/>`, it print the correct structure of file xml (but don't print always the random number).

Comment: Do you have access to any error output from the XSLT processor? Is it possible that it's telling you it can't find math.xsl, or doesn't recognize the function `math:random()`? Or that math.xsl is not compatible with the version of XSLT you're running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [EXSLT - math:random()](http://exslt.org/math/functions/random/index.html) documentation, the function is supported by the following XSLT processors: 4XSLT, libxslt, msxsl. What XSLT processor are you using?

According to [this page](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/configuration.xml), the default for ExistDB is Xalan, which is not one of the listed processors. (However, according to [Xalan's documentation](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/lib/ExsltMath.html#random%28%29), it does provide `math:random()`.)

If you haven't configured a different processor, that would be a good thing to try. My personal recommendation is Saxon. According to [its documentation](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.9.1/extensions.html), it supports EXSLT `math:random()`.

However, it sounds to me like your XSLT processor may not be getting invoked at all. Can you show us how you're telling ExistDB to run your stylesheet? Have you gotten it to run any stylesheets at all?

Comment: I agree with LarsH, there is something wrong in the way you are running the stylesheet.